# Join Polar data frame with varying multiple similar columns

Tags: python, python-polars

I am using polar library in python and have two data frames the look like this

```
import polars as pl

data1 = {
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': [4, 5, 6],
    'C': [7, 8, 9]
}

df1 = pl.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {
    'B': [4, 5, 6],
    'C': [7, 8, 9],
    'D': [1, 2, 3]
}

df2 = pl.DataFrame(data2)

# the column B and C are same in both data frames
# TODO: Join/Concat the data frames into one.
```

The data2 can vary some time it can have 2 common columns, some time it can have 1 common column and some times more. and The result should look like.  I was wondering if there is any built function, or some kind of flag in a function that exists already in polars, that i can use.

```
result = {
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': [4, 5, 6],
    'C': [7, 8, 9],
    'D': [1, 2, 3]
}
```

I am not quite sure how to `join` or `concat` the polar data frames in order to achieve this.

Comment: Did you try anything already?

Comment: Are you trying to do this without using `on=["B", "C"]`? e.g. `pl.concat([df1, df2], how="align")`

Comment: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.join.html explains the very flexible join method:

`df3 = df1.join(df2, on=["B","C"])`

Comment: @Deano . The common or similar columns could var, some time it can be two and some time they can be one. I was wondering if there is an in built function, or some kind of flag in a function that exists already  in polars, that i can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concat with [`how="align"`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.concat.html#polars.concat) but the resulting column order differs.

```py
pl.concat([df1, df2], how="align")
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ B   ┆ C   ┆ A   ┆ D   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 4   ┆ 7   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 5   ┆ 8   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   │
│ 6   ┆ 9   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

You can see how it is implemented [here.](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/main/py-polars/polars/functions/eager.py#L139-L163)

It basically finds the common columns to use as `on` and *"outer joins"* all the frames together.

```py
dfs = [df1, df2]

cols = pl.concat(pl.Series(df.columns) for df in dfs)
join_cols = list(cols.filter(cols.is_duplicated()).unique())

result = dfs[0].join(dfs[1], how="outer", on=join_cols, suffix="")

# only needed for more than 2 frames
# for df in dfs[2:]:
#    result = result.join(df, how="outer", on=join_cols, suffix="")

result = result.select(*cols.unique(maintain_order=True))
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ D   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 7   ┆ 1   │
│ 2   ┆ 5   ┆ 8   ┆ 2   │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ 9   ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Looks like i was checking at wrong place 
https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/transformations/concatenation/

Instead, I should be looking at here 
https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.concat.html